# redis/webdis & storm, publish with http post

Tags: redis, apache-storm

First a little explanation; I have a system, lets call it SystemA that I can configure to send http Posts to a url I specify when something goes wrong, but can't modify the request body directly.

My goal is to get the body of the post request to a storm spout via a redis pubsub queue.
I know I can publish to the redis pubsub channel by doing a POST to webdis like:

```
url: http://127.0.0.1:7379/
body:/PUBLISH/channelname/someimportantinfo
```

Since I can't modify the body of the POST from SystemA to prepend the /PUBLISH/channelname I was hoping I could structure the request like:

```
url: http://127.0.0.1:7379/PUBLISH/channelname
body:someimportantinfo
```

but that does not work; I don't get an error the event just never flows through the channel.

Any thoughts on how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be solved by adding a "***shim***" between SystemA and WebDis interface.
This ***shim*** will receive the HTTP post request from SystemA, extract the body and then send the request to Redis in the desired format.

Since you want to feed this data into Storm only when something goes wrong, I don't think this approach is going to be a bottle neck in your system (hopefully, your system isn't generating errors every second!).

Comment: Yes I agree, but I was hoping that webdis could be the shim between systemA and Redis, if I cant get webdis to work I will probably end up writing the intermediary to add the event straight to redis.